# Can you trap/identify if an object is being "invoked" as a function in runtime?

Tags: javascript

Given some basic class, such as a logical predicate class here:

```
const isACat = new Predicate(obj => obj.cat === true);
```

Is there a way to determine/trap/identify (perhaps via `Reflection`?) the context under which `isACat` is being "invoked/evaluated"?  By "invoke/evaluate"--because I can't really think of a better word to use right now--I mean something like this:

```
console.log(isACat(object1));  // being "invoked/evaluated" as a function
console.log(isACat);           // being "invoked/evaluated" as a non-function
```

I specifically mean this in the "runtime" sense, not in the `typeof/instanceof` sense.

For the ultimate goal of performing contingent behavior, such as (perhaps via a `Proxy`) returning a default function *if* that instance is being "invoked/evaluated" as a function.

**Edit:** Maybe in more precise terms, is there such a thing as a "default getter" when no further child prop is passed (i.e. `isACat`, but not `isACat[ prop ]`)?

Comment: I think the word you’re looking for is “referenced”, and, no, I don’t think what you want is possible. Think of it as the equivalent of being alerted to the use of a scalar value.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). It will help if you back up and ask about the original X.

Comment: You can detect if something is being called as a function, and you can tell if something is being dereferenced (from an object). But in order to call something, you have to dereference it first. And that dereferencing can happen on a previous line, way back in the code in another function, etc. So detecting `isACat(object1)` is easy. But detecting `isACat` is not really possible. Detecting `obj.isACat` is possible, but if you do `let isACat = obj.isACat`, you can't detect further uses of `isACat` by itself.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I suppose the general idea that I was intending was that in the case of `Predicate`, I want a return value of `unknown` in the cases of: no arguments, `null`, `undefined`, and perhaps others; where in the case of arguments passed, it should perform the actual evaluation.  This is trivial in the `isACat()` situation, but I suppose--in some sense--I want the `Predicate` to "be" `unknown` unless the evaluation actually takes place and is actually `true`/`false`.  Though it sounds like this is not really possible.

Comment: @Matt Sounds like you want `const returnValue = somePredicate;`. That's not just impossible, it also doesn't make sense - the return value and the predicate function are two different things, but JS assignment stores the *same* value in the target variable.

Comment: Fundamentally, this is a question about the contingent evaluation of a variable; it's just less obvious because of the syntax and appears in a way that JavaScript is (apparently) not normally capable of without a meta-level parser/interpreter/etc. that is, in some sense, context-aware.

Answer (score 1):

I am not seriously suggesting that you do any of the things presented bellow and you will spot their limitation immediately but I thought it was kind of fun to demonstrate.

```js
[{dog: true}, {cat: true}].filter(isACat);// (referenced(), [{cat: true}])

isACat({dog: true}); // (referenced(), false)

let lives = 0;
lives += isACat; // (referenced(), 7)

`Felix ${isACat}` // (referenced(), "Felix is a cat")
```

The above requires the following, which you could probably generate with a Babel plugin or something (I mean: don't, obviously)

```js
const referenced = (obj) => () => {
  console.log(obj, 'was referenced');
  return obj;
}

const _isACat = obj => obj.cat === true;
 
Object.defineProperty(_isACat, 'toString', {
  value: () => 'is a cat'
});

Object.defineProperty(_isACat, 'valueOf', {
  value: () => 7
});

Object.defineProperty(window, 'isACat', {
  get: referenced(_isACat)
});
```

I don't know what I like the most about it: deceiving expectations thanks to getters, magical type coercion, or local variables leaking to the global scope. It is pure poetry.

More seriously, I don't think Javascript is the language for this but if for some reason you need meta-programming power, maybe give Clojure a go. You can also use macros with ClojureScript, which compiles to Javascript and has Javascript interop, but there is a runtime/compile time distinction which will limit what you can do.

Comment: This is a fun snippet.  I like the idea of meta-programming, that might be something to play around with more.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such thing. You're just accessing a variable, or whatever the reference to your object is stored in, and you get back a reference value. The object itself has no say about  this process - it isn't even looked at yet. This is not "invocation" or "evaluation".

Really, if you need something like this, make the invocation explicit, and write `isACat()` (vs `isACat(object)` vs `isACat.prop()`).